# Which final layer to choose for best representative features of objects in Mask-RCNN?

Tags: object-detection

I would like to extract the features from the final layer of the Mask R-CNN (https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/image-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-ebe6d793272, https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN, https://github.com/multimodallearning/pytorch-mask-rcnn) to feed into another network, so would it be best to take gt_mask, det_masks (I was looking at https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/samples/coco/inspect_model.ipynb) or any other recommended layer?